# Remove same repeated points from list<poinf> with lambda expressions

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda

I have a list of float points as following:

```
wayPoints = (new PointF[] { 
new PointF(18, 0), 
new PointF(18,0), 
new PointF(55, 155),
new PointF(55, 155),
new PointF(55, 155),
new PointF(55, 155),
new PointF(55, 0),
new PointF(55, 230)}).ToList();
```

I want to use Lambda Expressions in which the same points removed from list but one of those same points stays in the list

Output:

```
wayPoints = 
(new PointF[] { 
 new PointF(18, 0),
 new PointF(55, 155),
 new PointF(55, 0),
 new PointF(55, 230)}
).ToList();
```

How should I write my commands in Lambda Expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just what a list of points then you can do this (No need for first doing a array and the `ToList()`):

```
var wayPoints = new List<PointF>{ 
    new PointF(18, 0), 
    new PointF(18,0), 
    new PointF(55, 155),
    new PointF(55, 155),
    new PointF(55, 155),
    new PointF(55, 155),
    new PointF(55, 0),
    new PointF(55, 230)
};
```

If you want the unique points. The you can use `Distinct`. Like this:

```
var wayPoints = (new PointF[] { 
new PointF(18, 0), 
new PointF(18,0), 
new PointF(55, 155),
new PointF(55, 155),
new PointF(55, 155),
new PointF(55, 155),
new PointF(55, 0),
new PointF(55, 230)}).ToList();
var uniquePoints=wayPoints.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

[Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb348436.aspx) removes duplicates:

```
var distinctPoints = wayPoints.Distinct();
```

However, the result will contain only one PointF(18, 0), even in a sequence like {(18, 0), (10, 10), (18, 0)}. I'm not sure if you want to preserve those points which are not consecutive.

Comment: If the input list be like :{(18, 0), (10, 10), (18, 0)} so

I want the result to appear like  {(18, 0), (10, 10)}

Comment: @farzin parsa: Then `Distinct` is the method of choice.